# JS code runs slow on codepen, though it runs good locally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented minimax algorithm for an unbeatable tic toc toe game.
The minimax algorithm is recursive, performing big iterations, which are not big for the computer, only big for humans.
The very first step takes about 3 seconds to perform on codepen, but performs instantly on my computer locally.
what's wrong? is my code not efficient? or it's a problem on codepen?
How do it make it efficient on codepen? 
Here's my JS code:

```js
var player;
var opponent;
var myMove = false;

var board = [
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null]
];

//displays modal
$('.play').click(function() {
  $('.modal').css("display", "block");
});

$('.O').click(function() {
  $('.modal').css("display", "none");
  player = 'O';
  opponent = 'X';
  resetGame();
  updateSymbol();
  main();
});

$('.X').click(function() {
  $('.modal').css("display", "none");
  player = 'X';
  opponent = 'O';
  resetGame();
  updateSymbol();
  main();
});

function main() {
  $(".col-xs-4").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':empty')) {

      var cell = $(this).attr("id");
      var row = parseInt(cell[1]);
      var col = parseInt(cell[2]);
      if (!myMove) {
        board[row][col] = false;
        myMove = true;
        updateMove();
        makeMove();
      }
    }
  });
}

function checkWin(board) {

  vals = [true, false];
  var allNotNull = true;
  for (var k = 0; k < vals.length; k++) {
    var value = vals[k];
    // Check rows, columns, and diagonals for win
    var diagonalComplete1 = true;
    var diagonalComplete2 = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      if (board[i][i] != value) {
        diagonalComplete1 = false;
      }
      if (board[2 - i][i] != value) {
        diagonalComplete2 = false;
      }
      var rowComplete = true;
      var colComplete = true;
      for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] != value) {
          rowComplete = false;
        }
        if (board[j][i] != value) {
          colComplete = false;
        }
        if (board[i][j] === null) {
          allNotNull = false;
        }
      }
      if (rowComplete || colComplete) {
        return value ? 1 : 0;
      }
    }
    if (diagonalComplete1 || diagonalComplete2) {
      return value ? 1 : 0;
    }
  }
  if (allNotNull) {
    return -1;
  }
  return null;
}


function resetGame() {
  board = [
    [null, null, null],
    [null, null, null],
    [null, null, null]
  ];
  myMove = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      $("#" + "b" + i + "" + j).text("").css("background", "#222");
    }
  }
  $('h3').css("display", "none").text("");
}




function updateMove() {
  updateSymbol();
  var winner = checkWin(board);
  if (winner === 1) {
    $('h3').css("display", "block").append(opponent + " won!!").addClass("animated infinite pulse");
    markWin();
    setTimeout(resetGame, 2000);
  } else if (winner === 0) {
    $('h3').css("display", "block").append(player + ' won!!').addClass("animated infinite pulse");
    markWin();
    setTimeout(resetGame, 2000);
  } else if (winner === -1) {
    $('h3').css("display", "block").append("It's a Draw!!").addClass("animated infinite pulse");
    markWin();
    setTimeout(resetGame, 2000);
  }
}


function updateSymbol() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] === false && $("#" + "b" + i + "" + j).is(':empty')) {
        $("#" + "b" + i + "" + j).text(player);
      } else if (board[i][j] === true && $("#" + "b" + i + "" + j).is(':empty')) {
        $("#" + "b" + i + "" + j).text(opponent);
      }
    }
  }
}

function markWin() {
  var arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [3, 6, 9],
    [1, 5, 9],
    [3, 5, 7]
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ($('.' + 'b' + arr[i][0] + ':contains("O")').length > 0 && $('.' + 'b' + arr[i][1] + ':contains("O")').length > 0 && $('.' + 'b' + arr[i][2] + ':contains("O")').length > 0) {
      $('.' + 'b' + arr[i][0]).css("background", "green");
      $('.' + 'b' + arr[i][1]).css("background", "green");
      $('.' + 'b' + arr[i][2]).css("background", "green");
      i = arr.length;
    }
  } //checks O win
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if ($('.' + 'b' + arr[j][0] + ':contains("X")').length > 0 && $('.' + 'b' + arr[j][1] + ':contains("X")').length > 0 && $('.' + 'b' + arr[j][2] + ':contains("X")').length > 0) {
      $('.' + 'b' + arr[j][0]).css("background", "green");
      $('.' + 'b' + arr[j][1]).css("background", "green");
      $('.' + 'b' + arr[j][2]).css("background", "green");
      j = arr.length;
    }
  } //checks X win
  return false;
}

//[0,0] [0,1] [0,2]
//[1,0] [1,1] [1,2]
//[2,0] [2,1] [2,2]

function minimax(board, player) {
  nodes++;
  var winner = checkWin(board);
  if (winner !== null) {
    switch (winner) {
      case 1:
        // AI wins
        return [1, board];
      case 0:
        // opponent wins
        return [-1, board];
      case -1:
        // Tie
        return [0, board];
    }
  } else {
    // Next states
    var nextVal = null;
    var nextBoard = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] === null) {
          board[i][j] = player;
          var value = minimax(board, !player)[0];
          if ((player && (nextVal === null || value > nextVal)) || (!player && (nextVal === null || value < nextVal))) {
            nextBoard = board.map(function(arr) {
              return arr.slice();
            });
            nextVal = value;
          }
          board[i][j] = null;
        }
      }
    }
    return [nextVal, nextBoard];
  }
}

function minimaxMove(board) {
  nodes = 0;
  return minimax(board, true)[1];
}

function makeMove() {
  board = minimaxMove(board);
  console.log(nodes);
  myMove = false;
  if (nodes !== 1) {
    updateMove();
  }
}
```

Here's the codepen link of my code:
http://codepen.io/makkBit/pen/JXgdEo/

Comment: It's running fine for me on CodePen. Takes no more than a few milliseconds to complete. The first prediction will always be the slowest.

Comment: This question is really better suited for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - cool app though

Comment: @wahwahwah this may be suited for Code Review as the code works, however reading the question it really seems to ask "why is it slower on CodePen than on my computer?" which is not really a good question for Code Review.

Comment: @Phrancis - Good point. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Phrancis rightly said.

Comment: From my experience, any online REPL/IDE is always slower than compiling/running the code locally, this does not exactly strike me as surprising.

Comment: @MikeC yeah first prediction will always be the slowest. But this much slow that it will consume 3 whole seconds? 
Also, the very first move locally only takes few milliseconds.

Comment: @Phrancis yeah I agree, but here its too slow, taking 3 seconds for a computer for almost 60000 iterations is a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a profiler to pinpoint where the code is slow.

Here's the profiler result using Google Chrome.

The problem seems to start from the function `minimaxMove`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I already know that. What I want to know is "why is it slower on CodePen than on my computer?"

Comment: Compare a profile done on CodePen vs a profile done on your computer directly.